# YAML parsing to Objects (PyYAML Python3)

Tags: python, pyyaml

I've got the following code:

```
class Settings:
    def __init__(self, annual_volatility_target):
        self.annual_volatility_target = annual_volatility_target
        self.daily = annual_volatility_target/np.sqrt(252)

def yaml_load(name):
    with open('yaml/' + str(name) + '.yaml', 'r') as ymlfile:
        return yaml.load(ymlfile)

settings = yaml_load("settings")
```

With the following YAML:

```
!!python/object:v.Settings
annual_volatility_target: 0.25
```

The problem is, when I load `settings`, `settings.daily` isn't set. `settings.annual_volatility_target` is, regardless of whether I say so in  `__init__` or not.

If I instantiate a `Settings` object manually (i.e. not using PyYAML), it works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: while the second answer seems easier to me, the first one is more complete and includes valuable data.

Comment: @Srgrn Which is the first and which is the second?

Comment: stupid of me. yours was the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python objects in PyYAML are constructed in a two step process. First `__new__` is called (in `Constructor.make_python_instance()`) and then the attributes are set (in `Constructor.set_python_instance_state()`). This two step process is needed because YAML supports references to objects and if that object is (indirectly) self referential it cannot be constructed in one go, because the parameters on which it depends (which include itself) are not available yet.

You can solve this in two ways. You can define `__setstate__()` for `Settings` and that will be called with a `dict` and call this from `__init__()` as well:

```
import yaml

yaml_str = """\
!!python/object:try.Settings
annual_volatility_target: 0.25
"""

class Settings:
    def __init__(self, annual_volatility_target):
        self.__setstate__({annual_volatility_target: annual_volatility_target})

    def __setstate__(self, kw):
        self.annual_volatility_target = kw.get('annual_volatility_target')
        self.daily = self.annual_volatility_target/np.sqrt(252)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Setting({}, {})".format(self.annual_volatility_target, self.daily)

settings = yaml.load(yaml_str)

print(settings)
```

Another, and more general (non PyYAML) solution is to create the `daily` value on first access:

```
class Settings:
    def __init__(self, annual_volatility_target):
        self.annual_volatility_target = annual_volatility_target

    @property:
    def daily(self):
         return annual_volatility_target/np.sqrt(252)
```

If you access `daily` often, then you should cache it in e.g. `self._daily` the first time you calculate the value:

```
class Settings:
    def __init__(self, annual_volatility_target):
        self.annual_volatility_target = annual_volatility_target
        self._daily = None

    @property:
    def daily(self):
         if self._daily is None:  
             self._daily = annual_volatility_target/np.sqrt(252)
         return self._daily
```

Comment: I've used your solution, but gone one step further, and removed __init__(), because as best as I can tell, it is *never* called by PyYAML. Is there any reason why I should leave it in?

Comment: @cjm2671 It helps to have `__init__()` if you want to instantiate objects of the class in test routines etc. But you don't really have to have it.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to write a [constructor](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#Constructorsrepresentersresolvers) for `Settings`:

```
import yaml
import numpy as np

class Settings:
    def __init__(self, annual_volatility_target):
        self.annual_volatility_target = annual_volatility_target
        self.daily = annual_volatility_target/np.sqrt(252)

def yaml_load(name):
    with open(str(name) + '.yaml', 'r') as ymlfile:
        return yaml.load(ymlfile)

def settings_constructor(loader, node):
    fields = loader.construct_mapping(node)
    return Settings(fields['annual_volatility_target'])

yaml.add_constructor('!v.Settings', settings_constructor)

settings = yaml_load("settings")

print(settings.annual_volatility_target)
print(settings.daily)
```

I have to use a modified `yaml` file (I was unable to make it work with annotation `!!python/object:v.Settings`):

```
!v.Settings
annual_volatility_target: 0.25
```

Comment: You don't have to write a constructor. PyYAML has build in mechanisms (`__setstate__`, subclassing `yaml.YAMLObject`) to deal with object loading as well.