# When ruamel.yaml loads @dataclass from string, __post_init__ is not called

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

Assume I created a `@dataclass class Foo`, and added a `__post_init__` to perform type checking and processing.

When I attempt to `yaml.load` a `!Foo` object, `__post_init__` is not called.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields

from ruamel.yaml import yaml_object, YAML


yaml = YAML()


@yaml_object(yaml)
@dataclass
class Foo:
    foo: int
    bar: int

    def __post_init__(self):
        raise Exception
        for field in fields(self):
            value = getattr(self, field.name)
            typ = field.type
            if not isinstance(value, typ):
                raise Exception

s = '''\
!Foo
foo: "foo"
bar: "bar"
'''
yaml.load(s)
```

How do I perform parameter checking when loading dataclasses via ruamel.yaml?

This behavior occurs in Python 3.7 as well as 3.6 with `pip install dataclasses`.

Comment: Since I learned Rust, I've started writing static factory methods instead of constructors. Maybe if I had this problem again, I'd approach it differently. Not sure.

Answer (score 6):

This is now supported in 0.17.34, where you can do

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()

@yaml.register_class
@dataclass
class Foo:
   ....
```

---

The reason why `__post_init__` is not called, is because `ruamel.yaml` (and the PyYAML code in its `Constructor`s), was created long before `dataclasses` was created.

Of course code for making a call to  `__post_init_()` could be added to `ruamel.yaml`'s Python object constructors, preferably after a test if something was created using `@dataclass`, as otherwise a non Data-Class class, that happens to have such a method named `__post_init_`, will all of a sudden have that method called during loading.

If you have no such classes, you can add your own, smarter, constructor to the `YAML()` instance before first loading/dumping (at which moment the constructor is instantiated) using `yaml.Constructor = MyConstructor`. But adding a constructor is not as trivial as subclassing the `RoundTripConstructor`, because all supported node types need to be registered on such a new constructor type.

Most of the time I find it easier to just patch the appropriate method on the `RoundTripConstructor`:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields
from ruamel.yaml import yaml_object, YAML, RoundTripConstructor


def my_construct_yaml_object(self, node, cls):
    for data in self.org_construct_yaml_object(node, cls):
      yield data
    # not doing a try-except, in case `__post_init__` does catch the AttributeError
    post_init = getattr(data, '__post_init__', None)
    if post_init:
        post_init()

RoundTripConstructor.org_construct_yaml_object = RoundTripConstructor.construct_yaml_object
RoundTripConstructor.construct_yaml_object = my_construct_yaml_object

yaml = YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True

@yaml_object(yaml)
@dataclass
class Foo:
    foo: int
    bar: int

    def __post_init__(self):
        for field in fields(self):
            value = getattr(self, field.name)
            typ = field.type
            if not isinstance(value, typ):
                raise Exception

s = '''\
!Foo
foo: "foo"
bar: "bar"
'''
d = yaml.load(s)
```

throws an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try.py", line 36, in <module>
    d = yaml.load(s)
  File "/home/venv/tmp-46489abf428c4cd4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/main.py", line 266, in load
    return constructor.get_single_data()
  File "/home/venv/tmp-46489abf428c4cd4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/constructor.py", line 105, in get_single_data
    return self.construct_document(node)
  File "/home/venv/tmp-46489abf428c4cd4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/constructor.py", line 115, in construct_document
    for dummy in generator:
  File "try.py", line 10, in my_construct_yaml_object
    post_init()
  File "try.py", line 29, in __post_init__
    raise Exception
Exception
```

Please note that the double quotes in your YAML are superfluous, so if you want to preserve these on round-trip you need to do `yaml.preserve_quotes = True`

Comment: Support for `__post_init__` has been added to ruamel.yaml as of 0.17.35

https://sourceforge.net/p/ruamel-yaml/tickets/355/

Answer (score 4):

I'm not entirely sure if this is the *correct* workaround...

I can move logic from `__post_init__` to `__setstate__(state: dict)`, which gets called by `YAML().load()`.

```
def __setstate__(self, state):
    self.__dict__.update(state)
    # I could call self.__post_init__(), or alternatively move logic here:
    for field in fields(self):
        value = getattr(self, field.name)
        typ = field.type
        if not isinstance(value, typ):
            raise Exception
```

`YAML().load(s)` calls `Foo.__setstate__(state)` if that method exists, but apparently not `__init__` (which calls `__post_init__`). Is this an intentional design decision?

Comment: Yes that is a an intentional design decision, it is similar to what pickle does. And if you `pickle.dump` your `Foo` instance (without `__post_init__`) and then try to `pickle.load` it **with** `__post_init__`, you'll notice it doesn't get called either. Also see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37260409/1307905)