# __post_init__ of python 3.x dataclasses is not called when loaded from yaml

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml, python-dataclasses

Please note that I have already referred to StackOverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51529458/when-ruamel-yaml-loads-dataclass-from-string-post-init-is-not-called). I post this question to investigate if calling `__post_init__` is safe or not. Please check the question till the end.

Check the below code. In step 3 where we load `dataclass` `A` from `yaml` string. Note that it does not call `__post_init__` method.

```py
import dataclasses
import yaml


@dataclasses.dataclass
class A:
    a: int = 55

    def __post_init__(self):
        print("__post_init__ got called", self)


print("\n>>>>>>>>>>>> 1: create dataclass object")
a = A(33)
print(a)  # print dataclass
print(dataclasses.fields(a))

print("\n>>>>>>>>>>>> 2: dump to yaml")
s = yaml.dump(a)
print(s)  # print yaml repr

print("\n>>>>>>>>>>>> 3: create class from str")
a_ = yaml.load(s)
print(a_)  # print dataclass loaded from yaml str
print(dataclasses.fields(a_))
```

The solution that I see for now is calling `__-post_init__` on my own at the end like in below code snippet.

```py
a_.__post_init__()
```

I am not sure if this is safe recreation of `yaml` serialized `dataclass`. Also, it will pose a problem when `__post_init__` takes kwargs in case when `dataclass` fields are `dataclasses.InitVar` type.

Comment: What if you load something that doesn't implement a __post_init__()? Can I ask you why you are using YAML to save objects instead of pickle?

Comment: All works fine if I do not implement __post_init__() but I want that to do some things when dataclass is loaded. I use yaml instead of pickle I want to build rest API for with clean yaml interface in future.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is working as intended. You are dumping an existing object, so when you load it pyyaml intentionally avoids initializing the object again. The direct attributes of the dumped object will be saved even if they are created in `__post_init__` because that function runs prior to being dumped. When you want the side effects that come from `__post_init__`, like the print statement in your example, you will need to ensure that initialization occurs.

There are few ways to accomplish this. You can use either the metaclass or adding constructor/representer approaches described in [pyyaml's documentation](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation). You could also manually alter the dumped string in your example to be ''!!python/object/new:' instead of ''!!python/object:'. If your eventual goal is to have the yaml file generated in a different manner, then this might be a solution.

See below for an update to your code that uses the metaclass approach and calls `__post_init__` when loading from the dumped class object. The call to `cls(**fields)` in `from_yaml` ensures that the object is initialized. `yaml.load` uses `cls.__new__` to create objects tagged with ''!!python/object:' and then loads the saved attributes into the  object manually.

```
import dataclasses
import yaml


@dataclasses.dataclass
class A(yaml.YAMLObject):
    a: int = 55

    def __post_init__(self):
        print("__post_init__ got called", self)

    yaml_tag = '!A'
    yaml_loader = yaml.SafeLoader

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, loader, node):
        fields = loader.construct_mapping(node, deep=True)
        return cls(**fields)

print("\n>>>>>>>>>>>> 1: create dataclass object")
a = A(33)
print(a)  # print dataclass
print(dataclasses.fields(a))

print("\n>>>>>>>>>>>> 2: dump to yaml")
s = yaml.dump(a)
print(s)  # print yaml repr

print("\n>>>>>>>>>>>> 3: create class from str")
a_ = yaml.load(s, Loader=A.yaml_loader)
print(a_)  # print dataclass loaded from yaml str
print(dataclasses.fields(a_))
```